# Double Integral using Polar Co-ordinates

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

Can someone please help me as to how to calculate this double integral using polar co-ordinates - please see attached picture: [double int. polar co-ords](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqta5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}} \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}r^{\frac{3}{2}} \ d \theta \ dr=$$ $$= \frac{\pi}{10}3^{\frac{5}{2}}$$

Comment: This is similar to how I was thinking to approach it but how did you get those limits?

Comment: Draw the region, it will be easier to see it, $x^{2}+y^{2} < 3 \rightarrow r < \sqrt{3}$ and $0<x<y \rightarrow \pi/4 < \theta < \pi$ @D.Chrystal

Comment: would the inner limits not be from π/4 to π/2?

Comment: Yes, my bad, you're right, Fixed! @D.Chrystal

Comment: Okay now with those limits should the inner ones not be the outer ones?

Comment: @cavallorosso OP is right, you have your $r$ and $\theta$ bounds reversed the way you have it written. I think a factor of $2$ disappeared, too, so the denominator should be $10$. Rest looks good though.

Comment: ops that's right ahah, I usually don't really care about the order as it's usually clear from the contest. Fixed! @D.Chrystal

Comment: Thank you so much guys! @cavallorosso would you be able to help me out with a similar question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3433074/double-integral-with-polar-co-ordinates

Comment: and @NinadMunshi

Comment: Sure, if the question is closed you can accept the answer. @D.Chrystal