# Double Integral with Polar Co-ordinates

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates, multiple-integral

Could someone please help me work out this double integral with polar co-ordinates. I'm getting my answer to be 2cos(θ)/π. See the attached picture: [double int. with polar co-ords](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcbSj.jpg)

Comment: what are your polar bounds?

Comment: the outer limit goes from pi/4 to pi/2 and the inner limit goes from 0 to 2cosθ

Comment: It would be beneficial for you to learn MathJax to write up your questions instead of posting pictures.

Answer (score 0):

The answer can't depend on $\theta$.

**Hint**:

It is the integral of a function on the upper half of the disc delimited by the circle with center $(1,0)$ on the $x$-axis and radius $1$. The polar equation of this circle, which passes through  the origin and has diameter $2$, is
$$r=2\cos \theta,\quad \text{ by the inscribed angle theorem.}$$

Comment: I got 1/2 - 1/pi. Is this right?

Comment: I obtain $\frac12$ only; Which integral in $\theta$ alone do you have?

Comment: in the integral from pi/4 to pi/2 i have (2cos^2θ)/pi

Comment: The integral is from $\theta=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$y>0 \Rightarrow 0 < \theta < \pi$$
$$(x-1)^{2}+y^{2} < 1 \Rightarrow x^{2}+y^{2} < 2x \Rightarrow r^{2} < r \ cos\theta \Rightarrow r < cos \theta$$

Thus $$I = \int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{cos\theta}\frac{rcos\theta}{r^2}r \ dr \ d\theta = \int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{cos\theta}cos\theta \ dr \ d\theta = \int_{0}^{\pi} cos^{2}\theta= \frac{sin(2 \pi)}{4}+\pi=\pi$$

Comment: what about the pi in the denominator?

Comment: just take it outside the integral and divide the answer by \pi, so that you get 1